# I closed the tag but i get TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tag on line 9: 'if'. Looking for one of: elif, else, endif

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

keep getting this error: TemplateSyntaxError: Unclosed tag on line 9: 'if'. Looking for
one of: elif, else, endif.

line 9 is:

```
 {% if users %}
```

and I believe I close it on line 20 with:

```
{$ endif %}
```

here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Users</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <<h1>Here are your users for AppTwo:</h1>
    {% if users %}
    <<ol>
      {% for person in users %}
      <<li>User Infor</li>
        <<ul>
          <<li>First Name: {{ person.first_name}}</li>
          <<li>Last Name: {{ person.last_name}}</li>
          <<li>Email: {{ person.email }}</li>
        </ul>
      {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {$ endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

the error message highlighted when running python manage.py runserver is:

```
"GET /users/ HTTP/1.1" 500 126895
```

thus i believe perhaps its having problems when accessing the script in another file.. here is the views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from appTwo.models import User
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'appTwo/index.html')

def users(request):

    user_list = User.objects.order_by('first_name')
    user_dict = {'users':user_list}
    return render(request,'appTwo/users.html',context=user_dict)
```

here is models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=264,unique=True)
```

here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from appTwo import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.users,name='users')
]
```

any help would be greatly appreciated -thnx

Comment: You have a `$` instead of `%` before `endif`.

Comment: ty RoToRa , idk how i didn't see that